# MongoError: Authentication failed. - trouble connecting to MongoLab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

I am trying to connect to MongoLab (sandbox). I'm using MEAN.

I've put the development and production strings inside mongo={} in credentials.js file. But I'm not sure how to put database username and password. I can see my username and pass on MongoLab website, but I'm unsure of the format to use, can you please leave an example?

Answer (score 1):

See the official [documentation](http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/). The connection URI is formatted like this:

`mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds012345-a0.mongolab.com:56789/sample-db`

You'll find the correct URI to your database on your admin page in Mongolab.

Comment: Strings are fine, that's all fine but username and pass are an issue